# Randomly pick numbers from one function to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, genetic-algorithm

Sorry for my ignorance in Python and programming in general. I am testing a function similar to this;

```
def test1(self):
    return x # This returns a set of numbers. e.g [1, 5, 7, 8, 12]
def test2(self, a, b):
    # now I want to pick two numbers randomly from test1 into the function test2 function.
```

This is my attempt, but it gives errors.

```
def test1(self):
    return x # This returns a set of numbers. e.g [1, 5, 7, 8, 12]
def test2(self, a, b):
    a = test1.[ random.randint(0, len(x) )]
    b = test1.[ random.randint(0, len(x)) ]
    return a, b
```

For example, in the first attempt I may have (5, 8) and the second time if I execute `test2` I should have a different value, such as (12, 1) etc. 
I do not understand how should I implement this.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I see zero effort here... why dont you take the time to learn the basics before asking a question like this?

Comment: It looks like there's no closing parentheses for `random.randint`

Comment: Sorry @antfuentes87 that’s not true!! I try my best. Yet I couldn’t get the logic.

Comment: You see errors.. well then tell us what they are. [ask]

Comment: You also have `test1.[` which is not the correct syntax for accessing arrays or lists.

Comment: Why does `test1` exist?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are going overkill on this and over complicating your task. First pass your list to `test1`, then you pass that result into `test2` and take 2 `choice`'s from that value and return them, both functions only need to receive one argument

```
from random import choice

def test1(x):
    return x 

def test2(x):
    a = choice(x)
    b = choice(x)
    return a, b

print(test2(test1([1, 5, 7, 8, 12])))
```

Comment: Thanks @vash. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Mass17 no prob take your time with these things slow down you will be okay ! also if this helped appreciate if you checked accept answer cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample).